# Swift UIButton Extension Animations Override

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, core-animation, swift-extensions

So I have a `UIButton Extension` that allows all the buttons in my app to have a nice subtle animation. But recently I have thought of giving a few buttons a special animation but I am not sure how to give those few buttons a specific different animation other than the one that I have set universally for all the `UIButtons`. Is there a way to `override` this animation for just a few specific buttons?

Code for the extension of the button animation universally:

```
extension UIButton {
   override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
   {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: nil)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing to do here is to create subclasses of `UIButton`s that all do different things, instead of creating extensions of `UIButton`. Extensions are supposed to add new functionality, not override existing methods, like `touchesBegan`.

You should delete your extension and write a `SubtleAnimationButton`:

```
class SubtleAnimationButton : UIButton {
   override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
   {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: nil)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
  }
}
```

And use `SubtleAnimationButton` instead.

For those buttons where you want to override the behaviour, you should use a different subclass. I'll call this `SpecialButton`.

```
class SpecialButton : UIButton {
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok! But how would I call this? Would I have to call this animation on every single button? Like is there a way I can make it default to the 'SubtleAnimationButton'? I don't mean to sound lazy I just have a lot of buttons within the app as most do of course.

Comment: Just replace every `UIButton` with `SubtleAnimationButton`. This can easily be done with the find and replace feature. @MattTheDev